# How to customise the reply header of quoted emails in Thunderbird?

Tags: email, thunderbird, templates, reply

I used to rely on the [Change quote and reply format](https://freeshell.de/~kaosmos/changequote-en.html) to customise the header in the replied emails. So it would turn this:

> On 01/01/2005 at 10:00, support@example.com wrote:
>
> Some email

Into this:

> ---- Original message -----
>   Subject: something
>   From: support@example.com
>   To: recipient@example.com
>   Date: 01/01/2005
>
> Some email

But in recent versions of Thunderbird this add-on has been disabled for being out-dated and no update is available.

Is there currently a way, native or otherwise, to do something similar?